# MongoDB fifo queue with Ruby

Tags: ruby, mongodb, mongoid

I wonder if it is possible to create a FIFO queue with mongodb and ruby(mongoid).

I am trying to use capped collections but I cannot see how I can pop my queue. There seem to be no methods in [collection](http://rdoc.info/github/mongoid/moped/frames/Moped/Collection) to do this.

What I am doing right now is:

```
$fifo = Mongo::Connection.new.db("fifo")

queue = "#{queue_name}_#{queue_type}"
unless $fifo[queue].find.present?
  $fifo.command(create: queue, capped: true, size: 10000000, max: 1000)
end 
$fifo[queue].insert(url: "http://www.example.com/unique001")
$fifo[queue].insert(url: "http://www.example.com/unique002")
$fifo[queue].insert(url: "http://www.example.com/unique003")
```

Which gives me a capped collection that looks like (from console)

```
> db.test001_high.find()
{ "_id" : ObjectId("503c4714236f440e9c000001"), "url" : "http://www.example.com/unique001" }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("503c4714236f440e9c000002"), "url" : "http://www.example.com/unique002" }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("503c4714236f440e9c000003"), "url" : "http://www.example.com/unique003" }
```

What I wonder is, is there a way in ruby to have a blocking pop on this collection? I must say I am not really familiar with mongodb and am just trying to create a fifo queue like I have in redis. So maybe I am approaching this problem the wrong way.

Comment: Have you looked at tailable cursors?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I implemented a FIFO queue for mongo in Java.  You should use the atomic operation [findAndModify](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/findAndModify+Command) to find the earliest entry from the queue collection, and remove the document (remove=true) or set a status field.

The other thing to be careful is that you should only be doing this with MasterOnly reads, or set your write-number equal to the number of nodes on write.  Otherwise you may get inconsistent result due to replication delay.